How do I know the real state of this docker container?
 "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 7046,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-05-17T04:25:57.721062063Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2023-05-17T01:25:21.135879756-03:00"
        },

I have this docker container that shows a finish date, but it remains with the "Running" status. What could cause this? Is there a way to know if there are any processes running in this container?
I need to know if this container is used and if not, I need to delete it to free up space on the server.

what does docker ps show; that is, is the container still running according to the output from that?

I can get a container in the same state by killing it and then running docker start on the stopped container.
Assuming that's what's happened to yours, then the actual state is that it's running. The FinishedAt contains the timestamp at which it stopped last time.
It's a little strange that FinishedAt is in local time and StartedAt is UTC, but you can see that the container was started 36 seconds after it finished.
So I think your container was stopped and then started again. And it is now running.
